# The Splitting Principle for Varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, k-theory

I am recently thinking of the following question (motivated by the splitting principle for vector bundles): Suppose $X$ is a projective smooth variety over an algebraically closed field $k$. Let
\begin{equation}
E_0\subsetneq E_1\subsetneq \cdots\subsetneq E_n
\end{equation}
be a sequence of vector bundles. By this I mean that each inclusion $E_i\subsetneq E_{i+1}$ realizes $E_i$ as a subbundle not only a subsheaf. Over $X$ there is no reason that $E_{i+1}\simeq E_i\oplus (E_{i+1}/E_i)$. Can we construct a projective variety $\pi: Y\to X$ such that
\begin{equation}
\pi^\ast E_{i+1}=\pi^\ast E_i\oplus \pi^\ast (E_{i+1}/E_i).
\end{equation}

Comment: As a remark, I notice that the proof of splitting principle in [Fulton] "Vector Bundles and K-Theory" relies on choosing an inner product over $\mathbb{P}_X(E)$, which doesn't work for more general fields $k$.

Answer (score 1):

No, this does not exist in general. For instance, let $X = \mathbb{P}^1$ and consider the tautological embedding
$$
\phi \colon \mathcal{O}(-1) \hookrightarrow \mathcal{O} \oplus \mathcal{O}.
$$
Assume $\pi \colon Y \to X$ is a projective surjective morphism such that $\pi^*(\phi)$ is a split embedding. Then there is an epimorphism
$$
\mathcal{O}_Y \oplus \mathcal{O}_Y \cong
\pi^*(\mathcal{O} \oplus \mathcal{O}) \to 
\pi^*\mathcal{O}(-1).
$$
In particular, the line bundle $\pi^*\mathcal{O}(-1)$ is globally generated. On the other hand, its dual $\pi^*\mathcal{O}(1)$ is also globally generated (because $\mathcal{O}(1)$ is globally generated on $X$). But this is obviously impossible.

Comment: Thanks! Can I think of your answer in this way: In general there is a "way" to split a given vector bundle, but one could not split a given vector bundle together with a given filtration.

Comment: I would rather say that you cannot split a subbundle by a **proper** morphism.